# tr command not able to direct the Output?

Tags: linux, sed, tr

I have got a file file.txt witch has got these entries

> NY
>
> LA
>
> SF

I ran the command tr '\n' ',' < file.txt and it successfully deleted all of the newline characters.

I need all of this output in the same file.txt file, so I redirected the output like this

> tr '\n' ',' < file.txt > file.txt,

but It does not put anything in the file.txt and the resultant file is empty, Can anyone explain to me why the output of **tr** is getting lost due to redirection.

Answer (score 6):

because it opens the output file first which deletes what is in the file and then feels nothing into the tr command and back out into the empty file

```
tr '\n' ',' < file.txt > file2.txt
```

will work

Answer (score 0):

since you have tagged your question with `sed`, I suggest a sed oneliner, also sed could change your file "in-place" with option "-i"

```
sed -i ':a $!N; s/\n/,/; ta' file
```

or with awk

```
awk '{x=x""sprintf($0",")}END{gsub(/,$/,"",x);print x}' file
```

no like sed, awk has no "in-place" changing option, you have to :

```
awk '...' file > /tmp/mytmp && mv /tmp/mytmp file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replace the newline with `,` you can us this

`awk 'ORS=","' temp.txt > file.txt`